# Как обновлять несколько полей таблицы используя условный оператор в SQL-запросе

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

Обновляю данные в таблице созданной в Room. При обновлении передаю 2 значения. Первое значение обновляю однозначно, второе нужно обновить только если текущее значение в таблице больше нового.

К примеру такой запрос если оба значения обновляю безусловно:

```
@Query("UPDATE orders SET order_amount = :amount, order_price = :price WHERE order_id =:id")
void update(Float amount, Float price, int id);
```

Пробовал вставлять после `SET` конструкцию `CASE WHEN order_price > :price THEN order_price = :price`. Но `CASE` подчеркивает с ошибкой:

> `<column name> expected, got 'CASE'`

Как правильно составлять подобный запрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

case возвращает указанное значение, а не выполняет операцию по условию. Поэтому следует использовать его так:

```
update orders
   SET order_price = case when order_price > :price
                      then :price else order_price end
...
```

Comment: Сработало. Спасибо!